# Linear ODE question with constant coefficients and nontrival solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Linear ODE with constant coefficients

$$a_oy^{(n)}+…+a_ny=0$$

has a nontrivial constant solution. Find $a_n$.

I've never done anything like this before and I have no clue how to do this.  How do I solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried solving it for $n = 1, 2, 3...$? Do you see a pattern? It really helps to share your thoughts and what you have done to get an idea of where you are at. Regards

Comment: I know $a_n$, $a_{n+1}$, etc. are supposed to be constant. Does that mean $a_n$ has infinite solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nontrivial constant solution means that there is a function $y$ which

1. satisfies the equation
2. is constant
3. that constant is not zero

All derivatives $y'$, $y''$, etc of a constant function are equal to $0$. Therefore, the equation takes the form
$$a_0 \cdot 0+a_1 \cdot 0+ \cdots + a_{n-1} \cdot 0+ a_n y = 0$$
Simplify this. Recall that $y$ is not zero. Make your conclusion about $a_n$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks!